# Запуск Mplayer через SSH

Tags: ssh, exec

При попытке запустить .sh скрипт через SSH, содержащий некоторые команды, в т.ч. и запуск плеера, видео начинает проигрываться в консоли. При попытке запуска .sh через консоль (не через SSH, а напрямую), работает корректно (плеер открывается и проигрывает видео). Команда на запуск плеера в .sh выглядит так:

> mplayer -fs -playlist /home/parallels/video/temp/playlist.txt -fixed-vo[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так выглядит этот ужас в консоли...
P.S.: Нашел по теме во такую вещь - http://zenux.ru/articles/35/. Вот как бы наоборот сделать?)))

Answer (score 1):

Если суть вопроса в том, как сделать что бы при запуске через ssh плеера видео начинало проигрываться в графическом окне той системы на которую мы зашли по ssh, то Вам надо сделать следующее:

1. Зайдя через встроенный терминал (не ssh), дать команду `echo $DISPLAY`. Вы получите значение на подобии `:0.0`
2. В sh скрипт запускающий плеер перед его запуском добавить:

   ```
   DISPLAY=:0.0
   export DISPLAY
   ```

   Значение для этой переменной взять именно то, которое вы видели в п. 1

Comment: Замечательно работает, спасибо! Если вам не сложно, порекомендуйте пожалуйста, что делать, если у меня два (и более) дисплеев?

Comment: Если дисплеи на одной системе, то посмотрите соответствующие переменные DISPLAY на них. В принципе X'овое приложение может выдавать картинку на любую систему, а не только на ту, на которой запущено приложение формирующее эту картинку. В таких случаях пишется `DISPLAY=ip-адрес:0.0`, на принимающей картинку системе в настройках X-сервера должно быть указано разрешение на прием соединений извне

Comment: это очень интересно. Скажите пожалуйста, где можно почитать про это поподробнее?

Comment: Попробуйте в гугле набрать что то типа 'удаленный запуск x-приложений' Можно понемногу нарыть то что требуется. Сама ssh плюс ко всему умеет пробрасывать трафик для X-ов.

Comment: @Mike опция выглядит `ssh -X`. ТСу - попробуйте с этой опцией.

Comment: @andy.37 я обычно пробрасывал без ssh, средствами самого X11

Comment: @Mike, это было больше ТСу, а не Вам, думаю, Ваш ответ верен, просто это способ сделать то же через консоль.